# How To Install LibreOffice Online from source?

Tags: server, compiling, libreoffice

I would like to set up a Droplet on D.O. with LibreOffice Online, building from source.

How would I go about this?
I've looked at the [guide](https://gist.github.com/m-jowett/0f28bff952737f210574fc3b2efaa01a) on github, but it appears to be outdated.

*Before anyone asks, I've tried the Docker image before, and it didn't work out.*